# Why NullPointerException is a runtime exception and RemoteException not?

Tags: java, exception, runtimeexception

A possible reason because a NullPointerException is a runtime exception is because every method can throw it, so every method would need to have a "throws NullPointerException", and would be ugly. But this happens with RemoteException.

And a possible reason because RemoteException is not a runtime exception, is to tell it client to treat the exception. But every method in a remote environment need throws it, so there is no difference of throwing NullPointerException.

Speculations? Was I clear?

Comment: how do people do in language that don't even have the concept of checked exceptions? what can you do that cannot be done cleanly in another language? the problem is people considering "failures" to be a special case instead of realizing that failure is the norm.  These kind of people like the big giant GOTO statements that checked exceptions are. State-testing methods? Timeouts? Naaaaah.  Big giant GOTOs *"if the sh!t hit the fan"*.  Pretty much a Java specifity and it certainly does **NOT** rally the entire Java community (eg the Spring framework has a big hatred towards them).

Comment: Webinator, the guy asked a perfectly reasonable question. There is no need to rant.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I won't  discuss the  decision, I'll just  quote the explanation of the decision from Ann Wollrath (who lead the design and implementation of Java RMI). This is extracted from this [message](http://archives.java.sun.com/cgi-bin/wa?A2=ind9901&L=rmi-users&F=&S=&P=36083) from the RMI-USERS archives (message from Jan 1999):

> The decision to make RemoteException a
>   checked exception and requiring remote
>   methods to list the exception in its
>   throws clause is not a religious one.
>   The decision is based on how to make
>   distributed computing reliable.  This
>   question comes up every once in a
>   while on our users list.  I have a
>   detailed response that I posted a
>   while ago.  Here it is if you are
>   interested.  I couldn't find it in the
>   rmi-users archive, so I included it
>   below.
>
> cheers,
>
> -- Ann
>
> ---
>
> > I'd like to address the rationale for
> >     making RemoteException a checked
> >     Exception, rather than a
> >     RuntimeException.
> >
> > 1) networks aren't reliable
> >
> > I wish that they were, but in fact,
> >     they're not.  Every network has
> >     transient failures.  You can build in
> >     network redundancy, but the fact is
> >     that most networks don't have that. 
> >     Intranets have transient failures, as
> >     does the Internet. So, every RPC made,
> >     is subject to a failure.  The types of
> >     failures may not have anything to do
> >     with the "network", per se; if your
> >     server runs out of file descriptors,
> >     your client will get a connect
> >     exception. This isn't a network
> >     failure, in the sense of the network
> >     being broken; your server is in a
> >     transient state of being resource
> >     starved.
> >
> > RMI is not designed to only handle the
> >     limited case that the whole network
> >     crashes when a single machine crashes.
> >     Such a network would be considered
> >     reliable, either everything is up or
> >     everything is down--there is no
> >     partial failure. RMI is targetted for
> >     a more general audience.
> >
> > 2) RPC failure can't be hidden from
> >     the client
> >
> > Partial failure is a fact of
> >     distributed programming; these
> >     failures can't be hidden to the
> >     program.  A failure shows up in the
> >     client, whether the exception is
> >     checked or unchecked exception, it
> >     still shows up.  So, how should such
> >     failures be indicated to the client?
> >
> > 3) checked exceptions foster more
> >     robust programs
> >
> > There was a time when Oak and the
> >     earliest version of Java did not have
> >     checked exceptions. Exception handling
> >     was advisory, and it was an unsafe
> >     world out there. It was our group (Jim
> >     Waldo and me in particular :-) that
> >     recommended that there be exceptions
> >     checked by the compiler. Jim was quite
> >     persuasive in his arguments, telling
> >     of a world where robust code would
> >     reign.  After some consideration, Java
> >     was retooled to have checked
> >     exceptions. Only those exceptions for
> >     which there was no recovery or reflect
> >     application errors would be unchecked
> >     (e.g., OutOfMemoryError,
> >     NullPointerException respectively). 
> >     And the world was safe again.
> >
> > Imagine the Java engineers' surprise
> >     when many exceptions in the Java API
> >     and compiler were changed from
> >     unchecked to checked, and the compiler
> >     enforced the distinction, they
> >     uncovered bugs in the implementations!
> >     So, the best efforts at handling error
> >     conditions, however well intentioned,
> >     was not good enough.  That compiler is
> >     useful for something :-)
> >
> > 4) RemoteException should be a checked
> >     exception
> >
> > Ok, so back on track here.  Since a
> >     RemoteException is a fact of life in a
> >     RPC call (see #1, #2) and checked
> >     exceptions force you to write safe
> >     code (#3), we thought that making
> >     RemoteException a checked exception
> >     was a good idea.  Writing robust
> >     distributed programs is hard enough,
> >     without having the compiler to help
> >     you with exceptions.
> >
> > So, some might argue that a
> >     RemoteException is a like an
> >     OutOfMemoryError; your program should
> >     fall over dead if a remote call fails.
> >     I disagree with this point. Yes, in
> >     some cases, there is no recovery from
> >     a RemoteException; but if you are
> >     writing a reliable distributed
> >     program, your client needs to catch
> >     failures and retry appropriately. 
> >     Perhaps you need to contact another
> >     server, or abort a transaction of some
> >     sort.  If the RemoteException is not
> >     handled, it will percolate up and
> >     crash your client (yuk).
> >
> > Others have stated that there are some
> >     remote interfaces that are used in
> >     both the local case and the remote
> >     case and the client should not have to
> >     deal with the exceptions in the local
> >     case, so RemoteException should not
> >     have to be in a throws clause and
> >     handling it should not be mandatory.
> >     Now, if we allowed remote interface
> >     methods to omit RemoteException and
> >     had an "rmic" switch to generate stubs
> >     that would throw an unchecked
> >     RemoteException, the *client* has *no*
> >     choice in the matter. The decision of
> >     exception handling should remain with
> >     the client. If you define an interface
> >     that only throws unchecked exceptions
> >     you can never write a client that
> >     wants compiler help in dealing with
> >     those exceptions.  We have already
> >     seen from the above example that
> >     checked exceptions fosters robust
> >     code.
> >
> > Another issue that has popped up now
> >     and again is that developers need to
> >     simply translate local interfaces and
> >     use them as remote interfaces. This
> >     may work for a small set of cases, but
> >     if the interface was not designed with
> >     concurrency and partial failure and
> >     call latency in mind, the protocol
> >     captured by the interface may not be
> >     appropriate to use in the distributed
> >     case.  Is enough information passed in
> >     those operations to make the
> >     operations idempotent? Perhaps, but
> >     most likely not.
> >
> > Putting RemoteException in every
> >     throws clause may seem like a pain,
> >     but its the price to pay for writing
> >     robust distributed applications.
> >
> > -- Ann Wollrath

Comment: She looks pretty convinced that people haven't written "robust distributed applications" [sic] in languages that don't even have the concept of checked exceptions.  I'd like to have a bit of what she was smoking last century, sounds strong :)

Comment: @Downvoter I **really** wonder why this answer has been downvoted. Even if you disagree with the author, I'm posting the **reference**, not an opinion. Emotional downvotes are ridiculous.

Comment: I can't imagine why anyone would downvote this when, regardless of one's feelings on checked exceptions, this is clearly probably the most correct answer to the question you could possibly get.

Comment: @Webinator It's not the point that people CAN write robust distributed applications in languages without checked exceptions; it's that it's easier to do with checked exceptions. I'd always pick a language where things are easy over a language where they are merely possible.

Comment: +1 - Definitely the authoritative response to the question asked, and and interesting read.

Comment: +1 - Even if I disagree to some extent, this looks like the perfect answer - good job!

Answer (score 4):

There is vastly more potential for `NullPointerException` than `RemoteException`.  Any code that calls a method on an object (meaning practically any Java code at all) could potentially throw a `NullPointerException`.  Only RMI code can throw a `RemoteException`.  This is a tiny subset of "all code."

When writing the RMI libraries, the designers decided to make the client code expect to deal with these exceptions.  Considering the nature of remote code execution, I think that's reasonable.

Answer (score 3):

The way I understand it is:

- RuntimeExceptions are thrown for things that were preventable.
- Exceptions are thrown for things that were unpreventable but recoverable
- Errors are thrown for things that were unpreventable and unrecoverable.

For example, NullPointerExceptions can always be avoided and are therefore unchecked exceptions. A RemoteException could occur when there is a network failure, which cannot be reasonably prevented before the method call and therefore is checked.

Comment: I think you reversed "Exceptions" and "RuntimeExceptions" in your list. `NullPointerException` is a `RuntimeException`.

Answer (score 0):

Besides `RemoteException` only applying to code from `java.rmi` and `javax.rmi` packages (and their subpackages), `RemoteException` is a type of `IOException`, much like `SocketException` is... and all `IOException`s are checked exceptions.

Comment: I'll not downvote you, but this answer is not a possible reason for not to be a RuntimeException. RemoteException could be just a type of Exception instead of IOExeption. Be an IOException is a decision made after decide to be checked exception.

Comment: All exceptions in Java dealing with communications are subclasses of `IOException`.  `IOException` (and any other classes that inherit from `Exception` rather than `RuntimeException`) is a checked exception, thus any classes that inherit from it are also checked exceptions.